# NULL value is coming after modify 2D array values through console/ at run time using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am learning Java and have not got good grip on the code at the moment. I have a 2D string array with all the values defined and want to gives the user an option to change the value of any row and any column in the array.

Here is my code:
I have defined my Array globally which is as under:

```
static int option=0;
    static String[][] resultCard =  new String[][]{ 
        { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"},
        { "Account1", "1", "2","3","4","5" }, 
        { "Account2", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, 
        { "Account3", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"},
        { "Account4", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"},
        { "Account5", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"}
    };
```

After that I have created a method in which I am trying to retrieve the values of first row and last column and want to change the values .

```
public static void courseModify5(){
    int courseId=0;
    int row=0;
    int newMarks=0;
    int oldMarks=0;
    Scanner courseModify = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(row=1; row<resultCard.length;row++){
            System.out.printf("\t Enter "+ row + " for "+ resultCard[row][0]+"\n");
    }
    System.out.print("Select any course to modify the marks");
    courseId = courseModify.nextInt(); 
    while(courseId<=0 || courseId>6){
        System.out.println("Enter numbers between 1 to 6");
        courseId=courseModify.nextInt();
    }
    while(courseId>0 || courseId<=6){           
                if(courseId==1){
                    System.out.println("The Marks in "+ resultCard[1][0] +" for " + resultCard[0][5] + " are " + resultCard[1][5] );
                    resultCard[1][5]+=Integer.parseInt(resultCard[1][5]);
                    System.out.println("Enter new marks");
                    newMarks=courseModify.nextInt();
                    resultCard[1][5]=toString(newMarks);
                    System.out.println("New marks are: "+resultCard[1][5]); //please note that at the moment I am getting the output after changing the value as NULL
                    break;
                } 
                else if(courseId==2){
                    System.out.println("The Marks in "+ resultCard[2][0] +" for " + resultCard[0][5] + " are " + resultCard[2][5] );
                    resultCard[2][5]+=Integer.parseInt(resultCard[2][5]);
                    System.out.println("Enter new marks");
                    newMarks=courseModify.nextInt();
                    resultCard[2][5]=toString(newMarks);
                    System.out.println("New marks are: "+resultCard[2][5]);
                    break;
                } 
                else if(courseId==3){
                    System.out.println("The Marks in "+ resultCard[3][0] +" for " + resultCard[0][5] + " are " + resultCard[3][5] );
                    resultCard[3][5]+=Integer.parseInt(resultCard[3][5]);
                    System.out.println("Enter new marks");
                    newMarks=courseModify.nextInt();
                    resultCard[3][5]=toString(newMarks);
                    System.out.println("New marks are: "+resultCard[3][5]);
                    break;
                } 
        break;
    }

}
```

I am a bit stuck here as the output which I am getting when I compile and change the array value is NULL. Also the value is not getting stored in the array as well.Any help and guidance will be highly appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: If you just want a code review you may contact http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow :).

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for the reply. I am trying to change the value in for example row 1 column 5 from 5 to 55 and the output I am getting is NULL. I just wana know where I am doing wrong. Is it that I have an array of string and the user input is in int and then convert it into string. I am not sure why I am not getting the desired output which user enters.
Regards

Comment: My first guess is a problem with `courseModify.nextInt()`. You're reading an int here but the line feed (which appears if you press Enter) is still in the input stream (where `Scanner` reads from) and the next `nextInt()` won't return a valid number (because `\n` can't be converted to one). Try `Integer.parseInt(courseModify.nextLIne())` to read your numbers and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: use debugger, I would recommend Netbeans, otherwise it is too wasteful just to communicate the character positions in your source.
BTW you don't have to enumerate "if(courseId==1)" just use the variable instead: resultCard[courseId][5]+=...

Comment: resultCard[1][5]+=... will append a string like "1"+2 yields "12" (not an integer sum!), since you have an array of strings.
better style would be to create a class record with individually typed fields (string for the first field and integers for the rest).